# How to show netlify the file it has to run?

Tags: python, flask, netlify

I have a web project written in python and Flask. I want to publish it with Netlify and for that to work it has to run the `main.py` file.

I know that in Heroku you have to create a `Procfile` to show it, maybe there is the same option in Netlify? Or is not possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: for those still searching: netlify only works with frontend kinda apps that do not use serving stuff. use pythonanywhere instead